# Find all possible values of $a, p$ for which $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + (1-2p)x_n + p^2$ converges, given $x_1 = a$ and $n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

> Given a recurrence relation 
>   $$
> x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + (1-2p)x_n + p^2\\
> x_1 = a\\
> n\in\Bbb N
> $$
>   find all values of $a, p \in\Bbb R$ for which $x_n$ converges.

First of all I tried to assume that the limit indeed exists. Then it must match a fixed point of the following equation:
$$
x = x^2 + (1-2p)x + p^2
$$
Which solving for $x$ gives:
$$
(x-p)^2 = 0 \iff x = p
$$

By this if the recurrence converges then it must follow that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = p
$$

Lets now take a closer look at the recurrence. I've shown that it must describe a monotonically increasing sequence, namely:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + (1-2p)x_n + p^2 \\
x_{n+1} = x_n^2 - 2px_n + p^2 + x_n \\
x_{n+1} = (x_n - p)^2 + x_n \\
x_{n+1} - x_n = (x_n - p)^2 > 0 \implies \boxed{x_{n+1} > x_n}
$$

By this the sequence in monotonically increasing no matter what initial conditions are given.

At this point I'm lost. How do one deduce the constraints for $a, p$ for $x_n$ to be convergent. Since the sequence is increasing I guess the problem may be reduced to "find the values of $a, p$ for which the sequence is bounded". Then the result should follow by monotone convergence theorem. The answer section suggests that:
$$
0 \le p - a \le 1
$$

Which [seems true based on the Cobweb plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dzb4j3cus4). But a plot in not a formal proof. Unfortunately I was not able to infer that result. What is a proper way to finish the problem?

Please note this problem is given in the limits section. So even derivatives are not available.

Comment: Perhaps this idea helps (it does not fit to 100%): We would like to show that $lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1} - x_{n} = 0$. We know that $lim_{n \to \infty} a^n = 0$ iff $|a| \leq 1$. Hence it is necessary that $|x_n - p| \leq 1$ for all $n$, better $|a-p| \leq 1$ since $x_0 = a$. This leeds to $-1 \leq p-a \leq 1$. This is not what you want, so I made a mistake somewhere, but perhaps it helps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first simplification is to define $y_n=x_n-p$. Then as you already proved
$$y_{n+1} -y_n=y_n^2\\
y_1 = a-p\\
n\in\Bbb N$$

the problem is now to find conditions on $y_1$ such that $y_n \to 0$, i.e to study the recurrence relation $y_{n+1}=f(y_n)$ with the fixed (independent of $a$ and $p$) function $f(x)=x+x^2$.

---

As $y_{n+1} -y_n=y_n^2$ the sequence is increasing, and the only possible limits are $-1$ and $0$ so

- if $y_1 >0$ then for all $n$, $y_n>0$ and the series does not converge.
- if $y_1 <-1$ then $y_2>0$ and once more for all $n$, $y_n>0$ and the series does not converge.
- if $-1 \leq y_1 \leq 0$ you can show by recurrence that for all $n$ $-1 \leq y_n \leq 0$, so $y_n$ is a bounded monotonous function and thus converges.

You finally obtain the condition
$$-1 \leq y_1 \leq 0$$
i.e
$$-1 \leq a-p \leq 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Instead of viewing it as a map on $x_n$, try examining what happens to $x_n-p$.

From the second to last line of your display, it's easy to work out that
$(x_{n+1}-p) = (x_n-p)^2 + (x_n-p).$

So the sequence $b_n=x_n-p$ (which converges exactly when $x_n$ does) is iterating under them map $t\mapsto t^2+t$.  Now you have one function to understand not a class.  It sounds like you have the tools necessary to verify this converges if the initial value $b_1$ is between -1 and 0.